# Check if email exists in MySQL database using NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im creating a user login/registration using NodeJs and MySQL to use on an Android school project, however am not sure how to check if a user already exists with the same email.

Below is my code.

ps I will hash the passwords.

```js
// registration
router.post('/register', (req,res)=>{
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email= req.body.email
    const phone= req.body.phone;
    const password= req.body.password;
    const password2 = req.body.password2;
    let errors = [];

    //Check required fields
    if(!name || !email || !phone || !password || !password2){
        errors.push({msg: 'Please fill in all the fields'});
        res.send({message:'Please fill in all the fields'});
    }

    //Check passwords match
    if(password != password2){
        console.log('Passwords dont match');
        errors.push({msg: 'Passwords dont match'});
        res.send({message:'Passwords dont match'});
    }

    //Check password length
    if(password.length < 6){
        errors.push({msg: 'Password should be atleast 6 characters'});
        res.send({message:'Password should be atleast 6 characters'});
        
    }

    if(errors.length>0){

    }else{
        connection.query('INSERT INTO users(name, email, phone, password) VALUES("'+name+'", "'+email+'", "'+phone+'", "'+password+'")',
               [name, email, phone, password]);

        res.send('Welcome');
    }
    });

    

module.exports = router;
```

Please help

Comment: Search with following query `select * from users where email='abc@mail.com'` and do validation before inserting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of this code:**

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO users(name, email, phone, password) VALUES("'+name+'", "'+email+'", "'+phone+'", "'+password+'")',
           [name, email, phone, password]);
```

**You can do by this:**

```
connection.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email ="' + mysql.escape(email) +'"', function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    //You will get an array. if no users found it will return.

    if(result[0].email.length > 0){  
        //Then do your task (run insert query)
        connection.query('INSERT INTO users(name, email, phone, password) VALUES("'+name+'", "'+email+'", "'+phone+'", "'+password+'")',
               [name, email, phone, password]);

        res.send('Welcome');
    }
  });
```